# Re-size Instance Class Memory Allocation

Tags: delphi, class, instance

I Use This Sample for Change Class at run-time :

```
procedure PatchInstanceClass(Instance: TObject; NewClass: TClass);
type
  PClass = ^TClass;
begin
  if Assigned(Instance) and Assigned(NewClass)
    and NewClass.InheritsFrom(Instance.ClassType)
    and (NewClass.InstanceSize = Instance.InstanceSize) then
  begin
    PClass(Instance)^ := NewClass;
  end;
end;

type
  TMyButton = class(TButton)
  Private
    FLogEvent : TNotifyEvent;
  public
    Property  Log : TNotifyEvent Read FLogEvent Write FLogEvent;
    procedure Click; override;
  end;

procedure TMyButton.Click;
begin
  Inherited;
  if Assigned(FLogEvent) then
     FLogEvent(Self);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PatchInstanceClass(Button1, TMyButton);
end;
```

My Problem is that TMyButton Size is different with TButton Because I Add this a NotifyEvent to TMyButton.
My Question is how can I Re-size memory Allocation for NewClass same Instance. :-)

Comment: Use an interposer class and you won't need any hack.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? This is the wrong solution with probability > 0.999.

Comment: You should not do it because resizing an object instance generally relocates an instance in memory and makes references to the instance invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I agree with the others - you should rethink your approach, as this smells a bit hacky. However I like hacky things - so I am going to show you how you can achieve what you are asking for.

The key is to not put anything inside your new class (as the InstanceSize needs to be the same) put it somewhere else - if you are using a newer Delphi version (2010 or higher) you can do it like this. Otherwise you need to modify the code a bit but I guess you get the idea:

```
uses
  Generics.Collections;

procedure PatchInstanceClass(Instance: TObject; NewClass: TClass);
begin
  if Assigned(Instance) and Assigned(NewClass)
    and NewClass.InheritsFrom(Instance.ClassType)
    and (NewClass.InstanceSize = Instance.InstanceSize) then
  begin
    PPointer(Instance)^ := NewClass;
  end;
end;

type
  TMyButton = class(TButton)
  private
    function GetLogEvent: TNotifyEvent;
    procedure SetLogEvent(const Value: TNotifyEvent);
  public
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Click; override;

    property LogEvent: TNotifyEvent read GetLogEvent write SetLogEvent;
  end;

  TMyButtonHelper = class helper for TMyButton
  private
    class var fLogEvents: TDictionary<TObject, TNotifyEvent>;
  public
    class constructor Create;
    class destructor Destroy;
  end;

{ TMyButtonHelper }

class constructor TMyButtonHelper.Create;
begin
  fLogEvents := TDictionary<TObject, TNotifyEvent>.Create;
end;

class destructor TMyButtonHelper.Destroy;
begin
  fLogEvents.Free;
end;

{ TMyButton }

destructor TMyButton.Destroy;
begin
  fLogEvents.Remove(Self);
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyButton.Click;
begin
  inherited;
  if Assigned(LogEvent) then
     LogEvent(Self);
end;

function TMyButton.GetLogEvent: TNotifyEvent;
begin
  fLogEvents.TryGetValue(Self, Result);
end;

procedure TMyButton.SetLogEvent(const Value: TNotifyEvent);
begin
  fLogEvents.AddOrSetValue(Self, Value);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PatchInstanceClass(Button1, TMyButton);
  TMyButton(Button1).LogEvent := Button1Click;
end;
```

Comment: Better just use virtual method interceptor when you do this

Comment: @Farzad Didn't the question ask how to re-size the instance?

Answer (score 1):

What you are attempting to do is impractical. You could perhaps do this if you could locate all references to the object. You'd need to do this because a re-allocation could result in the memory residing at a different address. And so you would need to update those references.

So you'd need to find:

- All the references in your code, and
- All the references in the VCL code.

The latter is much harder. The parent holds references to its children. The owner of the button holds references. The action framework can hold references, if I recall correctly. I'm sure there are other places where references are taken.

If you could find all the references, then you need to:

1. Reallocate the memory block with the new size.
2. Perform any initialisation of the new fields in your derived class.
3. Change the class of the object.
4. Update all references to the object.

Frankly, this is a terrible way to instrument UI events. You have many better options:

- Use an interposer class.
- Use virtual method interceptors.
- Handle the application's OnMessage event to filter the message queue.

You really should abandon your current solution to the problem.